# DBExpress: How to find a primary key field?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, dbexpress

I have a TSimpleDataSet based on dinamically created SQL query. I need to know which field is a primary key?

```
SimpleDataSet1.DataSet.SetSchemaInfo(stIndexes, 'myTable' ,'');
```

This code tells me that i have a primary key with name 'someName', but how can i know which field (column) works with this index?

Comment: `Select * from table1 join table 2 join storedprocedure3 join someview5 join ....` and what field would be primary ?

Comment: my queries working only with single table

Comment: but the library, would it provide this functionality, would have to work with any query

Comment: maybe the library have a solution for my problem...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Primary Key/Index can belong to several columns (not just one).

The schema `stIndexes` dataset will return the PK name `INDEX_NAME` and the columns that construct that PK/Index (`COLUMN_NAME`). `INDEX_TYPE` will tell you which index types you have (`eSQLNonUnique/eSQLUnique/eSQLPrimaryKey`).

I have never worked with `TSimpleDataSet` but check if the indexes information is stored in 
 `IndexDefs[TIndexDef].Name/Fields/Options` - if `ixPrimary` in `Options` then this is your PK. and `Fields` belongs to that index.

Take a look at the source at `SqlExpr.pas`: `TCustomSQLDataSet.AddIndexDefs`.
Note how `TCustomSQLDataSet` returns the `TableName` (and then the indexs information) from the command text:

```
  ...
  if FCommandType = ctTable then
    TableName := FCommandText
  else
    TableName := GetTableNameFromSQL(CommandText);
  DataSet := FSQLConnection.OpenSchemaTable(stIndexes, TableName, '', '', '');
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the simple data set does not provide that information.

However, i am sure there are components for that. Check, for Oracle database, [Devart's ODAC](http://www.devart.com/odac/).
Basically, it involves only one query to the database. 
However, it is not something that components will offer by default as, because it involves a different query, it leads to slow response times.

For Oracle database, query on `user_indexes`.